# Add email subject to file name when saving attachment

Tags: vba, outlook, email-attachments

My goal is to extract the `.png` files of emails in the Outlook Inbox sub folder named Infuse Energy Daily Usage Reports.
[image]

The emails each contain six `png` files. The largest is the only one I need; it is exactly 37.6KB. The next largest file is 22.5KB. The third largest is 18.2KB.

The code mostly does what I need.

I want to add the full subject of the email to the beginning of the file name.

The file name should be:
**"Email Subject, Creation Time ("yyyymmdd_hhnnss_"), Original File Name of PNG Image."**

```vb
Sub SaveAttachmentsToFolder()
' This Outlook macro checks a named subfolder in the Outlook Inbox
' (here the "Infuse Eneregy Daily Usage Reports" folder) for messages with attached
' files of a specific type (here file with a "png" extension)
' and saves them to disk. Saved files are timestamped. The user
' can choose to view the saved files in Windows Explorer.
' NOTE: make sure the specified subfolder and save folder exist
' before running the macro.
    On Error GoTo SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err
' Declare variables
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim Inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim SubFolder As MAPIFolder
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim Atmt As Attachment
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim varResponse As VbMsgBoxResult
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set SubFolder = Inbox.Folders("Infuse Energy Daily Usage Reports") ' Enter correct subfolder name.
    i = 0
' Check subfolder for messages and exit if none found
    If SubFolder.Items.Count = 0 Then
        MsgBox "There are no messages in the Infuse Energy Daily Usage folder.", vbInformation, _
               "Nothing Found"
        Exit Sub
    End If
' Check each message for attachments
    For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
' Check filename of each attachment and save if it has "png" extension
            If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "png" Then
            ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
                FileName = "C:\Desktop\Energy Comparisons\Infuse Reports (from email)\" & _
                Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                i = i + 1
            End If
        Next Atmt
    Next Item
' Show summary message
    If i > 0 Then
        varResponse = MsgBox("I found " & i & " attached files." _
        & vbCrLf & "I have saved them into the Infuse Reports (from email)." _
        & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Would you like to view the files now?" _
        , vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Finished!")
' Open Windows Explorer to display saved files if user chooses
        If varResponse = vbYes Then
            Shell "Explorer.exe /e,C:\Desktop\Energy Comparisons\Infuse Reports (from email)", vbNormalFocus
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "I didn't find any attached files in your mail.", vbInformation, "Finished!"
    End If
' Clear memory
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit:
    Set Atmt = Nothing
    Set Item = Nothing
    Set ns = Nothing
    Exit Sub
' Handle Errors
SaveAttachmentsToFolder_err:
    MsgBox "An unexpected error has occurred." _
        & vbCrLf & "Please note and report the following information." _
        & vbCrLf & "Macro Name: GetAttachments" _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Number: " & Err.Number _
        & vbCrLf & "Error Description: " & Err.Description _
        , vbCritical, "Error!"
    Resume SaveAttachmentsToFolder_exit
End Sub
```

Comment: Using the *"Email Subject"* as filename would not work without filtering out characters that are not allowed in file names. You need to replace those or at least strip them off. • Please note that you only described what you want but not what is wrong with your code. Any errors? If not what does your code do versus what did you expect it to do? What exactly is your issue? • Giving some examples of what result you get of your code and what result you want might help to understad what's going on.

Comment: Allow me to clean up my request a bit. To correct my original post, the emails containing the energy reports contain no attachments. The macro I'm currently using is pulling the png graphics embedded within the email, which is fine. However my interest is particularly one specific graphic displaying a chart & table with data usage in half hour increments. If I can automate the extraction of these details that would be preferred. I will update or add a comment to my post to provide more detail.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to iterate over all items in a folder:

```
 For Each Item In SubFolder.Items
        For Each Atmt In Item.Attachments
```

This is not really a good idea because it can take a lot of time to iterate over all items in a folder. Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or Restrict methods of the `Items` class. Filter Example: [Attachment & Subject Like '%keyword%']

```
Filter = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & _
                   Chr(34) & " Like '%keyword%' AND " & _
                   Chr(34) & "urn:schemas:httpmail:hasattachment" & _
                   Chr(34) & "=1"
```

Read more about these methods in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

As for the filename of attachments saved to the disk, you need to make sure there are no forbidden symbols included to the filename before calling the `SaveAsFile` method.

```
If Right(Atmt.FileName, 3) = "png" Then
            ' This path must exist! Change folder name as necessary.
                FileName = "C:\Desktop\Energy Comparisons\Infuse Reports (from email)\" & Item.Subject & _
                 Format(Item.CreationTime, "yyyymmdd_hhnnss_") & Atmt.FileName
                Atmt.SaveAsFile FileName
                i = i + 1
            End If
```

Also be aware, an Outlook folder may contain different kind of items. I'd suggest checking the item's type at runtime to make sure you deal with mail items only. The [Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.class) property returns an [OlObjectClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.olobjectclass) constant indicating the object's class. Or just use the following condition:

```
If TypeOf Item Is MailItem Then
 ' your code here
End If
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I have created an illustration to put into perspective what the action of the current macro results. This is a macro that I have used for years to isolate attachments from emails and I just wanted to clean it up or re-create it in some form to handle my current project requirements.

Comment: The screenshot in the link here shows the original email. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tXhkwwBu79_WUh8bItPC-JYtrPkK4zGW/view?usp=sharing


The screenshot here shows what the current macro yields. 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1tXhkwwBu79_WUh8bItPC-JYtrPkK4zGW/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I have described in my post what can be done.